# Why does foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have created a Post model and i want to create a Post 
with a form. But if i submit the form it gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`internetstuffer`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `text`, `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (vsvsvdv, sdsdfsdf, 1, 2016-07-26 12:13:34, 2016-07-26 12:13:34))
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong because i have created a function that sets the user_id.

Here is my setUser_id() from my Post model:

```
public function setUser_id() {
    $this->attributes['user_id'] = Auth::user()->getId();
}
```

Here is my HomeController.php:

```
 public function postForum(Request $request) {
    $post = Post::create($request->only(['title', 'text', 'category_id']));
    $post->setUser_id();
    $post->save();
    return back();
}
```

And here is my form:

```
                   <form method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"> <br> <br>
                            <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="text"> <br> <br>
                            <select name="category_id">
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{ $category->getId() }}">{{ $category->getName() }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                            </select> <br> <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Post">
                        </form>
```

Comment: Your post requires a user_id on the insert. Constraint fails probably in the `$post->setUser_id()` function because it's not showing on the insert

Answer (score 1):

`Model::create` calls `save()` on the created model so you have to add user_id to the array you send to the create function

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? How do i add user_id to the array?

Comment: You could get it into a variable and add it to that first. `$data = $request->only(['title', 'text', 'category_id']; $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->getId(); $post = Post::create($data);`